# DataTables: Confirm user wishes to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

We have a number of jQuery DataTables that all use server side processing.  We have paging and sorting set up, and all is working well.  In these tables there is at least one column of checkboxes to allow selecting of rows to do some kind of processing on.  We want to confirm that the user wishes to page or sort if there are any checkboxes checked.

### What I thought I could do (and can't)

```
"fnPreDrawCallback" : function(table) {
    if (CullAddress.AddressIsChecked()) {
        var $warningDiv = $('div#pageWarning');
        var warningText = "One or more Addresses are selected for Excluding or Tagging.  Are you sure you wish to nvaigate away?";
        $warningDiv.find("div#pageWarningText").html(warningText);
        $warningDiv.dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: "auto",
            width: "auto",
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Leave Page": function () {
                    CullAddress.resetWarningText();
                    $warningDiv.dialog('close');
                },
                "Stay On Page": function () {
                    CullAddress.resetWarningText();
                    $warningDiv.dialog('close');
                    return false;
                }
            },

        });
    }
},
```

Initially I thought this would be simple, but now, it is getting a bit hefty, and I am not sure of what the right way is.  I am trying to use the fnPreDrawCallback, and initially I intended to create and display a jQueryUI Dialog, and have the buttons determine whether or not to `return false;` out of the callback thus staying on the page, or allowing the page/sort to go through.

I now understand that javaScript does not work that way.  I suspect I will have to do the following, but before I go through that trouble I want to ask if there is a more concise (and reusable) way of doing this.

- In fnPreDrawCallback, get properties to describe the intended set page/sort (e.g. offset, pageSize, sSortDir, iSortCol, etc).
- Determine via dialog whether to continue or stay on page
- Use aforementioned properties to construct the GET for the datatable to bypass the fnPreDrawCallback

Am I making this more difficult that it needs to be?  Surely I am not the first person to want to do this, but for the life of me, I can find an example, or I cant figure out the keywords I should be searching for...

Any helps?

Comment: what is happening when you return `false` right now?

Comment: right now it appears to continue execution of the function and go ahead and page/sort regardless.  The execution does not wait for the button press or return.  It shows the dialog, binds the buttons, then assumes that it can continue.

Comment: oh, i see, of course it doesn't wait. Unfortunately, I can't really think of an elegant solution myself right now. As a quick-fix, you could bind handlers to the paging and sort - links, stop the default behaviour and call the API - functions yourself after the user made his choice. Have a look at `fnPageChange` and `fnSort` for this in the API (http://datatables.net/api)

Comment: @CodeWarrior Sounds like you want to intercept the paging and stop it depending on a user's input... Here's a similar [post](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/5704/help-to-customize-events-of-paging/p1) I don't know of a solution myself. You may try posting on the DataTables forum.  Allan is quite active on there.

Comment: Yeah I saw that one.  And posted  at http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/14546/interrupting-a-pagesort-to-query-the-user#Item_1 yesterday.  No replies yet, however.

Comment: @CodeWarrior i just created a small example of what i was thinking about: http://jsfiddle.net/6frQZ/

Comment: That would work well, unfortunately we are using the numbered pages (i.e. First < Prev < 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 > Next > Last) and Product Owner is married to that concept.

Comment: @CodeWarrior not that much of a problem either: http://jsfiddle.net/6frQZ/1/

Comment: @CodeWarrior updated the example to work with sorting too, posted it as answer now so we don't misuse the comment-section too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link to working example: http://jsfiddle.net/6frQZ/3/

As already discussed in the comments to the question, I tried to circumvent the default behaviour of DataTables to fit your needs and created an example [on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6frQZ/3/) to show, including numbered-pagination and sorting.

Basically, you'll need to unbind the event-handlers, that the DataTables - plugin binds to it's components, like so:

```
$('.dataTables_paginate a').unbind();
$('.dataTables_wrapper thead th').unbind();
```

Using `.unbind` without a parameter will unbind any event-listener on the element, so be careful when using this.

Gladly, the DataTables - API provides functions that let you call the internal paging and sorting-methods yourself, named [fnSort (API-Link)](http://datatables.net/api#fnSort) and [fnPageChange (API-Link)](http://datatables.net/api#fnPageChange).

To keep it simple, i just used a `confirm` - Box to ask for the user-interaction:

```
var userInteraction = confirm("Do you really want to change the page?");

if(userInteraction){
    oTable.fnPageChange(dir);
    $('.dataTables_paginate span a').unbind();
}
```

but all you'd need to do is call the DataTables-functions inside of your `"Leave Page"` - callback you already provided in the code.

**Note**: When it comes to the numbered buttons of the paging: It seems like DataTables regenerates those everytime the paging is changed, thus I need to unbind the event-Handlers again after every page-change.

The rest is simple yet not very elegant code, in which I just look for certain classes to know, what button was clicked or which state the sorting-header is in.

Excerpt:

```
var dir = "",
    $this = $(this);

if($this.hasClass('previous')){
    dir = "previous";
}else if ($this.hasClass('next')){
    dir = "next";
}else if($this.hasClass('first')){
    dir = "first";
}else if($this.hasClass('last')){
    dir = "last";
}else{
    dir = parseInt($this.text(),10)-1;
}
```

Comment: That looks like it will work.  I will have to modify it to use JQueryUI dialog (so that it meshes with the rest of the page style) but otherwise that works.  Thanks!

Comment: I had to modify this just a tiny bit.  I wrapped up the unbinding and the new click binding in `fnInitComplete` so that all configuration of the dataTable was complete before unbinding.  For whatever reason, my unbind was not working when it immediately followed the dataTable setup.